# Multiprocess Bogosort

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.x, multiprocessing

I only program by hobby, and I'm trying to improve with Python, so along with practicing coding I decided to venture into multiprocessing. This is a command line and will sort a variable number of list, timing itself. I also tried to make sure I followed all PEP8 rules.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Random Sort
# supernova2468


import sys
import time
import random
import math
import multiprocessing as mp
import argparse


def go_time():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Makes statistics on how terrible random sorting is.')
    parser.add_argument('start', help='what length of list to start at',
                        type=int)
    parser.add_argument('end', help='what length of list to end at', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--tries',
                        help='specify number of tries per length default: 100',
                        type=int, default=100)
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--cores',
                        help='specify number of cores to use default: 1',
                        type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose',
                        help='increase output, doesn\'t '
                        'really work in -c mode',
                        action='count')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    start = args.start
    end = args.end
    tries = args.tries
    if args.cores:
        cores = args.cores
        switch = 1
    else:
        switch = 2
        cores = 1

    if args.verbose >= 1:
        print 'Checking Parameters..'
    if end <= start:
        print 'ERROR: Must start before ending'
        sys.exit()
    if tries < 1:
        print 'ERROR: Must have at least one interation'
        sys.exit()
    if tries < cores:
        print 'ERROR: Must have at least one try per core'
        sys.exit()
    if end < 0:
        print 'ERROR: No negative numbers'
        sys.exit()

    print 'Beginning Trials..'

    program_start = time.time()

    if switch == 1:
        try:
            if args.verbose >= 1:
                print 'Starting Pool'
                print ('Warning: Multiple Process Output '
                       'Causes Console Confusion')

            mp.freeze_support()
            pool = mp.Pool(processes=cores)
            split_tries = math.ceil(tries/cores)
            result_list = []
            split_stat_list = []
            stat_list = {}

            if args.verbose >= 2:
                print 'split tries {}'.format(split_tries)

            for i in range(cores):
                if args.verbose >= 1:
                    print 'Process {}'.format(i)
                result_list.append(
                    pool.apply_async(
                        r_sort, (start, end, split_tries, args.verbose)))

            for r in result_list:
                split_stat_list.append(r.get(99999))
            pool.close()

            for single_dict in split_stat_list:
                for c in range(start, end+1):
                    try:
                        stat_list[c] += single_dict[c]
                    except KeyError:
                        stat_list[c] = single_dict[c]

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pool.terminate()
            sys.exit()

    elif switch == 2:
        if args.verbose >= 1:
            print 'Starting Single'
        stat_list = r_sort(start, end, tries, args.verbose)

    program_end = time.time()

    print 'Avg Results'
    print 'len {:^10} {:^10}'.format('time', 'attempts')
    print '---|{:-<10}|{:-<10}'.format('', '')

    for l in range(start, end+1):
        num2 = stat_list[l][0]/tries
        num3 = stat_list[l][1]/tries
        print '{:>3}|{:^10}|{:^10}'.format(l, round(num2, 8), num3)
    print 'Total Time: {}'.format(program_end-program_start)


def r_sort(start, end, tries, verbose):
    random.seed()
    current_length = start
    stat_list = {}

    while current_length < end+1:
        i = 0
        time_total = 0
        attempts_total = 0

        while i < tries:
            # actual sorting
            the_list = range(current_length)
            rand_list = list(the_list)
            random.shuffle(rand_list)

            if verbose == 1:
                str_width = str(len(str(tries)))
                print ('List Length {} current_length '
                       '{:0>{width}}/{:0>{width}}\r'
                       .format(current_length,
                               i+1, tries, width=str_width),)

            start_time = time.time()
            attempts = 1

            while the_list != rand_list:
                random.shuffle(rand_list)
                if verbose >= 2:
                    print 'list: {} | {}'.format(rand_list,
                                                 mp.current_process().pid)
                attempts += 1

            stop_time = time.time()

            time_total += stop_time-start_time
            attempts_total += attempts

            i += 1

        stat_list[current_length] = [time_total, attempts_total]
        if verbose == 1:
            print ''
        current_length += 1

    return stat_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    go_time()
```

Answer (score 4):

Good job using `ArgumentParser`.

It is a very, very nice tool that should be used more often in Python.

---

Near the top of your code where you are doing a bunch of checks on parameters, you have a `sys.exit` call if the user did something wrong when entering parameters.

However, you don't pass in any exit number.

The method `sys.exit` takes a single parameter that is the exit code. This exit code describes how execution of the program went to external programs.

By practice, any non-zero number means that something went wrong. Therefore, I recommending doing one of the following:

- Return 1 if there was any sort of error in the code.
- Return 1, 2, 3... for each individual and possible error.

The second one is more preferable because, if you create some documentation for the program, you can include a list of all the possible exit codes and what error they are associated with.

---

A few times in your code, you have these lines:

```
if args.verbose >= 1:
    [print statement(s)]
```

Since these repeat so much, you should create a function probably called `print_verbose` that takes in a string to print that should only be printed if the user chose for a verbose execution.

Here is what I wrote:

```
def print_verbose(str):
    if verbose:
        print str
```

Where verbose is a global variable that was set like this by `go_time`:

```
verbose = true if args.verbose >= 1 else false
```

*Hint: This used python's [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator).*

And, by setting global `verbose` to a boolean rather than keeping it as a number, you've increased efficiency because you now don't have to do conditional checking upon an integer every time you want to print a string.

*Note: this does remove the ability of being able to write `args.verbose >= 2`, however, in my opinion, if the user wanted verbose output, then they wouldn't mind a few extra lines on their screen.*

---

Your code seems to be following PEP8 very well.

However, while this is not required by PEP8, you do not have any docstrings in your code. Docstrings are always a good practice in python.